# Launching GUI on BeagleBone via putty

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, beagleboneblack

How to launch a GUI application on a BeagleBone that is running Linux (Debian 7.4) remotely?

Notes:

1. putty is being used for the remote access.
2. The task is to have the GUI launched and displayed on the BeagleBone itself (i.e., no X11 forwarding)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `DISPLAY` variable after you have logged in using PuTTY:

```
export DISPLAY=":0"
```

Then you should be able to start an GUI application like `xclock`

**Note**: You need to login using PuTTY as the user who has a running desktop environment.

Confirm your regular value for the `DISPLAY` variable from a desktop session on the BeagleBone itself using a terminal issuing `export|grep DISPLAY`

No X11 forwarding is necessary when you use PuTTY to connect from another host.

To start such GUI process in the background use:

```
export DISPLAY=":0"
xclock &
```

If the commands needs to be run as root, it might be necessary to set an additional environment variable in the `ssh` session:

```
export XAUTHORITY=/home/user/.Xauthority
su -c xclock &
```

And it may even take a change to the `sudo` configuration if you want to use sudo to launch the application:

```
visudo
Defaults env_keep+=XAUTHORITY
sudo xclock &
```

Comment: I run export | grep DISPLAY and I got declare -x DISPLAY=":0" however when I run the command to start the application, I got: Server is already  active for display 0

Comment: Are you trying to start X over a `ssh` connection? Did you find and read http://www.x.org/wiki/FAQErrorMessages/#index5h2. My answer assumed that you have a working GUI desktop and you just want to open another application to be displayed on the GUI desktop.

Comment: Yes I have a working GUI desktop and I just want to open another application to be displayed on that GUI desktop. This is the exact setup that I am having.

Comment: What exact command are you using in your PuTTY session?

Comment: I am issuing sudo xinit /usr/local/bin/rtlizer on the BeagleBone. As for the putty I am not using any special setting or any thing, just traditional login.

Comment: Remove the `xinit` part from your command since `xinit` is used to start X (see http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/xinit.1.html) hence the error message you are receiving (server is already active).

Comment: okay, I got another message which is saying "No protocol specified"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24759/discussion-between-lambert-and-oah).

Comment: On windows OS the export of display is not enough. You need xming tool (http://www.geo.mtu.edu/geoschem/docs/putty_install.html)